# Plotly - how do I exclude a section of the y-axis, or reset the zero axis?

Tags: python, plotly

I have an example graph which shows some readings versus time. The y values are always in the range (-inf, -100] to [100, inf). In other words, the zero is at 100 (or -100, they're both considered the same), and so I'd like to exclude that section of the graph.

I tried using the `update_yaxes` method with `rangebreaks` param as follows :
    `fig.update_yaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(bounds=[-100, 100])])` but that did nothing.

Is there another method I can use? I basically want to remove the large gap between -100 and 100, since its effectively the same value.

[image: Example image]

Comment: If for the y values "_the zero is at 100 (or -100, they're both considered the same)_", then you just need to "normalize" those values accordingly : `y = np.abs(y_data) - 100`.

Comment: I think that would work, but I still need to display the data as it is. So for example I want -105 to still appear as -105, not -5.

Answer (score 0):

The doc at https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/ says "rangebreaks only work for "date" axis type"

One approach might be to rescale your data to remove the gap - i.e. add 100. to negative values and subtract 100. from positive values. Then specify *ticklabels* so that the Y axis is still labelled correctly

Another (more speculative, but might allow a visible break pattern to be displayed) would be to transform your y-values to dates (e.g. fist transform them to positive integers and then use *fromordinal()*), then use *rangebreaks* and, again, use *ticklabels* to get the axis labelled correctly.